# Convert single xml node as array to json

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, json.net

I have following code like this in my stored procedure. I am converting this xml to json using Newtonsoft library. The department may have single or multiple values. I want forcefully make it as array while converting this xml to json. How can I do it. How can I add json:Array='true' into my department node in sql stored procedure. And what changes I need to do in my C# code.

```
SELECT @xml = (
select p.fname,p.lname,
(
   select dept.name, dept.address
   from department dept inner join tbloffice off on off.officeid = dept.officeid
   where off.officeid=p.officeid
   FOR XML PATH('dept_detail'), TYPE
)
from person p
WHERE p.id = @ID
FOR XML PATH('person'), ROOT('export_person'), TYPE
)
RETURN @xml
```

For Multiple Records:

```
<export_person>
<person>
<fname>James</fname>
<lname>Williams</lname>
 <dept_details>
     <name>Engineering</name>
     <address>117, street</address>
  </dept_details>
  <dept_details>
     <name>Science</name>
     <address>119, street</address>
  </dept_details>
</person>
</export_person>
```

For Single Record:

```
<export_person>
<person>
<fname>James</fname>
<lname>Williams</lname>
 <dept_details>
     <name>Engineering</name>
     <address>117, street</address>
  </dept_details>
</person>
</export_person>
```

The multiple department record getting formed as

```
{
  "export_person": {
    "person": {
      "fname": "James",
      "lname": "Williams",
      "dept_details": [
        {
          "name": "Engineering",
          "address": "117, street"
        },
        {
          "name": "Science",
          "address": "119, street"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want this single department record should also look like

```
{
  "export_person": {
    "person": {
      "fname": "James",
      "lname": "Williams",
      "dept_details": [
        {
          "name": "Engineering",
          "address": "117, street"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

currently it getting formed as

```
{
  "export_person": {
    "person": {
      "fname": "James",
      "lname": "Williams",
      "dept_details":
        {
          "name": "Engineering",
          "address": "117, street"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently I am using following C# code to form the json. I am collecting data from person node discarding export_person wrapper.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
List<XElement> lstXelements = xmlExp.Elements().ToList();
List<dynamic> lstXelementJson = new List<dynamic>();

foreach (XElement Xele in lstXelements)
{
    string nodeName = lstXelements[0].Name.LocalName.ToString();
    doc.LoadXml(Xele.ToString());
    var jsonData = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc))[nodeName];
    lstXelementJson.Add(jsonData);
}
```

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Why don't you just create it as JSON in the first place, using `FOR JSON`?

Comment: Our one application needs xml and then for another function I need json so I am creating XML in stored procedure

Comment: Without sample data, and the expected results [you were asked to provide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68070177/convert-single-xml-node-as-array-to-json#comment120311102_68070177) by @YitzhakKhabinsky, we can't help you A. A. We can't run your SQL to get the data you currently have, and we can't read your mind to know what that data should look like.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question. Instead of using FOR XML, you could use Linq to get the data and simply convert to JSON using Newtonsoft. It would be much simpler IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried generating the JSON directly from SQL Server?

```sql
declare @JSON nvarchar(max) = (
  select
    p.fname as 'export_person.person.fname',
    p.lname as 'export_person.person.lname',
    (
      select
        dept.name,
        dept.address
     from dbo.department dept
     inner join dbo.office [off] on [off].officeid = dept.officeid
     for json path
    ) as 'export_person.person.dept_details'
  from person p
  where p.id = @ID
  for json path, without_array_wrapper
);
select @JSON as someColumnName;
```